# Can a quantity grow indefinitely at a rate proportional to its square?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In theory, a quantity can grow indefinitely at a rate proportional to its size.  Exponential growth.  But can it grow indefinitely at a rate proportional to its square?  Separating the variables, integrating and solving shows the quantity "blows up" in finite time which depends on the initial size of the quantity.  I get this.  But does (can) the physical process of growth continue indefinitely?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $Q'(t)=kQ(t)^2.$ Since this is growth we are talking about, we expect $Q'(t)\gt0,$ with $k\gt0,$ and this must hold trivially, because $Q(t)^2\gt0$ as long as $Q(t)\neq0.$ In that case, $$\frac{Q'(t)}{Q(t)^2}=k=\left(-\frac1{Q}\right)'(t),$$ so $$A-kt=\frac1{Q(t)}$$ for $Q(t)\lt0,$ which implies $t\gt\frac{A}{k},$ and $$A-kt=\frac1{Q(t)}$$ for $Q(t)\gt0,$ which implies $t\lt\frac{A}{k},$ and thus, $$Q(t)=(A-kt)^{-1}.$$ Notice, thus, that $$kQ(t)^2=k(A-kt)^{-2},$$ while $$Q'(t)=-(A-kt)^{-2}(-k)=k(A-kt)^{-2}.$$ So it satisfies the desired equation. Now, notice that for $t\gt\frac{A}{k},$ the function grows indefinitely, as it encounters no more asymptotes. However, it does not grow unbounded, because $$\lim_{t\to\infty}Q(t)=0.$$

As such, there is no function that grows indefinitely and unbounded satisfying a growth proportional to its square.